# How to rewrite URL without .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been reading up on this on the web, but still could not figure out how to implement it properly. I'd greatly appreciate if you could help me understand how to make url rewrite work without .htaccess.

To check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled, I ran command `~# sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`. It produced, among others the following module: `rewrite_module (shared)`. I don't know if it is the same as `mod_rewrite`?

Folder `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` has file `rewrite.load`

I'm not clear which file exactly I should add rewrite rules to?

File `httpd.conf` located in `/etc/apache2/` is empty. However there's a file named `000-default` located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` and it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not clear at all where I should add rewrite rules. I tried adding them to this `000-default` file into `<Directory /var/www/>` section, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the rewrite code in the directory block where you're have the .htaccess file (if you use them).   For example if /var/www is your docroot, you could put it their:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </Directory>
```

Comment: It's not working for me for some reason. What I'm trying to do is to remove `.php` extenstion in the url. As you instructed I have added the rewrite rules (that work in .htaccess) to `<Directory /var/www/>` of 000-default file, so it now look like this, but does not work: `<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]</Directory>`

Comment: @dmit this worked in your .htaccesss file?  What directory was the .htaccess file in?

Comment: Also can you provide in your OP a before and after URL example?

Comment: I have it in `Root directory>httpdocs`. I moved it Root directory and it works as well. Example, before: www.mysite.com/login.php; after: www.mysite.com/login

Comment: I'm not understanding.  Do you mean your code and `.htaccess` file is in `/var/www/httpdocs` ?

Comment: Also, you are you restarting your server every time you change your Conf file?  .htaccess files don't require a restart, config file changes do.

Comment: Yes. I do restart after I change the file. Sorry for the confusion. I added htaccess to httpdocs to check rules. but server htaccess is here `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/.htaccess`

Comment: What is the server name or server aliases in this file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache 2.2.16 or newer, use

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```